# Javascript Canvas Custom Cursor Hover - Animate CC

Tags: javascript, flash, html5-canvas

Hi im using Adobe Animate CC. I have a custom cursor, and my default cursor is hidden. The problem is, when i have a button symbol the mouse pointer still appears on top of the custom cursor.

```html
var display = this;

display.mc_play_button.addEventListener("click", play_game.bind(this));
function play_game()
{
 alert('Lets Play');
}

stage.cursor = 'none';
display.mc_cursor.mouseEnabled = false;
display.addEventListener("tick", custom_cursor.bind(this));

function custom_cursor() {
 display.mc_cursor.x = stage.mouseX;
 display.mc_cursor.y = stage.mouseY;
}
```

Comment: If you're using a button symbol, a `pointer` cursor is asigned automatically when you pass the mouse over. Try replacing the button symbol with a Movieclip symbol.

Comment: I have never used Animate CC but if it can access the canvas then you can set the hardware cursor via the style property. When you need the custom cursor set `canvas.style.cursor = "url('cursorImageURL.png') 10,10, pointer";`  where the 10,10 is the hotspot. When the mouse is no longer over the button then restore the cursor `canvas.style.cursor = "default";`